# Dynamic Routing via hostname, is it possible?

Tags: domain-name-system, dynamic

I am using a dynamic IP service to access my home PC's remotely and maintain that DNS is updated when my IP changes.

I run 5-6 machines and I would love to be able to do machine1.mydomain.com and have it route to the right LAN ip.

This way I could access all my local machines without having to VPN in, or setup some complex port forwarding.

Is this even possible?

Comment: what do you mean by '**do** machine1.mydomain.com' and '**access** all my local machines'? Access using what?

Comment: Mostly remote desktop (RDP)

Comment: On the IP layer it is impossible to route packets based on hostname. If you want something on the IP layer there is only one solution, and that is to upgrade to IPv6. If you want a solution at a higher layer, then it is certainly possible to do - with some protocols. But you haven't said which protocol you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

The practical answer for you is to continue to use VPN. You can setup a VPN to connect 2 networks.

When you have a dynamic IP, you will use private prefixes for internal networks. Those are not allowed to be routed via Internet.

To have IPs that can be routed, you either need to ask your ISP to provide a prefix of public addresses, or you need to create an AS (autonomous system) and ask an LIR or RIR (local/regional Internet Registry) to assign you a PI (provide independent) prefix. Both solutions are more expansive than your current setup. Also they involve a much more complex setup for your network infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can - Check IF your ISP assigned you Public IPv6 Addresses and see if your other provider supports IPv6.

With IPv6 Addresses, you will be able to establish end-to-end communication via the Internet.

As far as VPN goes, I guess you have 2 options:
1. Setup a VPN directly to your Internet Router (provided it offers this feature - easiest/less secure option).

2. Setup an SSTP VPN Server (on Windows Server) or setup an OpenVPN Server (On Linux - more secure/more involved).